# ADFS 2.0 Errors Event ID 184 & 364

Tags: windows-server-2008, troubleshooting, adfs

I have ADFS servers set up and each component such as in URN, relay, claims etc. in place, but am getting this error massage

> "There was a problem accessing the site. Try to browse to the site again. If the problem persists, contact the administrator of this site and provide the reference number to identify the problem. Reference number: a0d4e1a6-bfc5-471d-a1d2-0503ef658f4e"

The event log contains a record with
`Event ID 184`

> Error 
>   "A token request was received for a relying party identified by the key 'urn:myWebFrontEnd:adfs', but the request could not be fulfilled because the key does not identify any known relying party trust. Key: urn:myWebFrontEnd:adfs
>
> This request failed.
>
> User Action If this key represents a URI for which a token should be issued, verify that its prefix matches the relying party trust that is configured in the AD FS configuration database."

and a record with `Event ID 364`

> Error
>   "Encountered error during federation passive request.
>
> Additional Data
>
> Exception details: Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidScopeException: MSIS7007: The requested relying party trust 'urn:simswfeqas001:adfs' is unspecified or unsupported. If a relying party trust was specified, it is possible that you do not have permission to access the trust relying party. Contact your administrator for details. at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken request) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.RequestBearerToken(MSISSignInRequestMessage signInRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, SecurityToken primaryAuthToken, String desiredTokenType, Uri& replyTo) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.RequestBearerToken(MSISSignInRequestMessage signInRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, SecurityToken primaryAuthToken, String desiredTokenType, MSISSession& session) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(String signOnToken, WSFederationMessage incomingMessage) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SecurityToken securityToken, WSFederationMessage incomingMessage) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.BuildSignInResponseForProtocolRequest(FederationPassiveContext federationPassiveContext, SecurityToken securityToken) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.BuildSignInResponse(SecurityToken securityToken)"

How can I resolve these problems?

Comment: Have you seen these articles: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/adfs2-troubleshooting-fedpassive-request-failures(v=ws.10).aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/adfs2-troubleshooting-token-issuance-problems(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I'm having similar problems. I don't know if the source is the same as this or not. I have additional detail on my problem [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/276720/adfs-acting-like-it-has-a-relying-party-identifier-blacklist).